# Apache Ignite upgrade from 1.8 to latest version

Tags: upgrade, ignite

Can anyone please provide the steps to upgrade the apache ignite from 1.8 to latest version.

Comment: This is not really a programming question, so I don't think it's a good fit for SO. Having said that, Ignite 1.8 is such an old version that you're not likely to find a simple guide; a lot has changed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a best way in your case is to export your data in some format (CSV for example), and then import it back.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, but that requires a down time of the service.